# fatal error: can't unsafeBitCast between types of different sizes

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to parse the JSON Response, create instances of a model and populate the tableview.

This is my the response:

```
{
  "jsonrpc": "2.0",
  "id": 1,
  "result": [
    {
      "token": "4L12XJHPWM18",
      "name": "Berlin",
      "nameShort": "BLN",
      "country": "Germany",
      "mapLat": 52.5078884,
      "mapLng": 13.4392219,
      "mapZoom": 13,
      "timezone": "CET"
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

This is how I fetch it and parse it

```
Alamofire.request(.POST, BGAPIBaseUrlV1, parameters: JSONObject, encoding: .JSON)
    .responseJSON { (request: NSURLRequest, response: NSHTTPURLResponse?, object: AnyObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if (object != nil) {
            var responseDic = object as [String: AnyObject]
            var result: AnyObject? = responseDic["result"]
            if let resultArray = result as? Array<Dictionary<String, AnyObject>> {
                if (success != nil) {
                    success!(resultArray)
                }
            }
        }

        if (error != nil) {
            failure!(error!)
        }
}
```

No problem until I try to loop through th Array that I pass to the closure

```
APIManager.fetchCities({ (cities: Array<Dictionary<String, AnyObject>>) -> Void in
    for tmpCity in cities {
        var city: CityModel = CityModel(dict: tmpCity) <----------
        self.tableViewData.append(city)
    }

    self.tableView.reloadData()
}, failure: { (error: NSError) -> Void in
    println("It didn't work")
})
```

I get and EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION and the following error

> fatal error: can't unsafeBitCast between types of different sizes

Any idea why?

Answer (score 3):

Probably you substitute something with `String!` type in your "...", e.g. you will have the error if use:

```
var str: String! = ""
var data: NSDictionary = [ "myString": str ]
```

but

```
var str: String = ""
var data: NSDictionary = [ "myString": str ]
```

will work fine.